# Oracle - How to repeat query for every year/month/week

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I've made a query to get the rows from my chosen columns where the date is 2018 December:

```
SELECT myColumn1, myColumn2 
FROM MyTable
WHERE to_char(myColumn_DATE, 'YYYY/MM') = '2018/12'
```

This is quite simple and I can now use these rows to create some further logic. However what if I need to repeat this for every month in a given year, or even every week?

I'm exporting the query results into separate excel tables, so I guess I would have to manually check the correct date intervals every time and can't aggregate the data for a whole year/month/etc. Isn't there some PL/SQL approach to avoid this tedious repetition?

Comment: Thanks MattSom.  Are you looking for a query that includes data for a whole year but divides the results up by week -- for example including a week-of-year field?  Or are you looking to just repeat the query for different weeks iteratively?

Comment: I would go with repeating the query, as I'm going to use a lot of aggregate functions on the result rows to get some measurements on that time period. Of vourse if dividing the whole year is an easier approach, I'm very much open to suggestions like that as well!

Comment: How are you exporting the data? So far, you are merely showing all rows rows in a given range. You can rewrite this to `WHERE myColumn_DATE >= DATE '2018-12-01' AND myColumn_DATE < DATE '2019-01-01'` or more general with bind variables to `WHERE myColumn_DATE >= :date_start AND myColumn_DATE < :date_after`. Of course you can run this query in a loop in some programming language, e.g. VBA.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner
Awkward to say, but currently I am exporting it manually via SQL Developer. I'm still trying to figure out my sqlplus cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you're on a day from December 2018, and your aim is to populate the table `MyTable2` through the data from the table `MyTable`.

Firstly, let's create `MyTable2` without data :

```
create table MyTable2 as
select myColumn1, myColumn2 
  from MyTable
 where 1 = 9;
```

and then create a procedure by which populate MyTable2 on the last day of every month

```
create or replace procedure pr_populate_Mytable2 is
begin
   insert into MyTable2
   select myColumn1, myColumn2 
     from MyTable
    where to_char(myColumn_DATE, 'YYYY/MM') = to_char(sysdate,'YYYY/MM');
 commit;
end;
```

by calling the procedure from a `dbms_scheduler` as

```
declare
    v_job_name varchar2(32) := 'jb_populate_Mytable2';
begin  
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name => v_job_name,
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action => 'pr_populate_Mytable2', 
        start_date => to_date('31-12-2018 20:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYMONTHDAY=-1; BYHOUR=21;',
        auto_drop => false,
        comments => 'Populates our table on the last day of every month at 21 o''clock ');

    dbms_scheduler.enable(v_job_name);    
end;
```

starts at 8pm on the last day of december, and repeats on every upcoming last days of the  months at 9pm in the future.

Comment: Wow, interesting approach! However, for now I need to get all the information from the past time periods to make more complex data analysis. Still this option interests me very much! So you are saying, that calling a procedure with this so called `dbms_scheduler` will run my script at that given time? What if my server shuts down accidentally, will it miss the actual queries forever?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, will run at given time even after resurrection of db instance. You can prevent them running after restart by setting `job_queue_processes` value to zero, if your DB's version is `11gR2 +`. By the way,Budapest, where I've been last summer , is such an admirable city :) Hope you living well there.

Comment: Thanks for the information!
Thank you for the kind words as well, the city is sure lovely with the warmer weather now! :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CONNECT BY LEVEL <=` trick to generate rows, and then use a combination of date functions to generate the relevant dates.

```
--Months for the current year.
select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'year'), level-1) the_month
from dual
connect by level <= 12;

THE_MONTH
---------
2019-01-01
2019-02-01
2019-03-01
2019-04-01
2019-05-01
2019-06-01
2019-07-01
2019-08-01
2019-09-01
2019-10-01
2019-11-01
2019-12-01
```

Then create an inline view with that query, and join it to the main table:

```
select *
from
(
    --Months for the current year.
    select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'year'), level-1) the_month
    from dual
    connect by level <= 12
) months
left join mytable
    on months.the_month = trunc(mycolumn_date, 'month');
```